# JavaScript - How to display the current URL as a link in current window?

Tags: javascript, html, url

In my current window, I need to display the current URL(`document.URL`) as a link. If I click that link, it will open the same page in a new window.

Comment: `<a href="your link here">Name of link here</a>`

Comment: Add target="_blank" attribute also to the above comment. It will open the link in a new window.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do something like this.. Maybe you can improvise on this...

```
<a href="#" id="link" target="_blank">Link</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("link").href = window.location.toString();
}
</script>
```

Comment: There's no reason to put your code into `window.onload`, since it's located **after** the element

Answer (score 6):

No need for JavaScript in order to do this, you can simply use a relative path:

```
<a href="./" target="_blank">Hello</a>
```

This would mean 'link to the current window'

Comment: Note to OP : this may open in a new window or in a new tab, depending on the browser and its settings. There's no way to force it to really be a "new window".

Answer (score 2):

You can create a link with id like

`<a id="page-url" href="#">URL</a>`

Then in javascript

```
document.getElementById('page-url').href = document.URL
```